# What is the difference between console.log("Result" +vaRiable) and console.log("Result", vaRiable)?

Tags: javascript

Please be kind, I am a self learner. I try to find answers on my own sometimes.

````
```vaRiable =['2','4','6']

console.log("Result:"+vaRiable);
console.log("Result:",vaRiable);```
````

a particular array

```
vaRiable =['2','4','6']
```

when I  `console.log("Result :" +vaRiable);`  `output = Result:2,4,6`

```
console.log("Result :", vaRiable); output = Result: ['2','4','6']
```

what is the **'+'** doing to the string?
Why is there two types of output?
Can somebody quip me a one liner.It'll be great help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`"Result:"+vaRiable` is a *single* expression. The `Result:` string is concatenated with the `vaRiable`, creating another string. When an array is coerced to a string, its elements are joined by commas. So you get `'Result:' + '2,4,6'`, or `Result:2,4,6`. That one string is then passed to `console.log` and printed to the console.

In contrast:

```
console.log("Result :", vaRiable);
```

sends *two* parameters to `console.log`. They don't get concatenated together, because they're separate parameters. When multiple parameters are passed to `console.log`, each is logged individually (though on the same line).

Answer (score 0):

When you perform `"Result:"+vaRiable` the value of `vaRiable` is being `type coerced` into a string so that it can be concatenated to `"Result"`. What you're doing in the first example is essentially creating a new string equal to `"Result:2,4,6"` because that's what arrays look like when they're cast to strings, similar to calling `[2, 4, 6].toString()` or `[2, 4, 6].join(',')`.

In the second example, `console.log()` is doing regular console output of the array, which is why it keeps the brackets; it knows it's an array and to give it special formatting.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `("Result:" + vaRiable)`, what the **+** is doing is to **concatenate** your string with your array into a single whole string.

When you do `("Result:", vaRiable)` you're printing two *messages*. In this case you're not concatenating, the first message is a string `Result:` and the second message is an array `['2','4','6']`.